# gsutil rsync exclude patterns not working on Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, escaping, parameter-passing, gsutil

I'm trying to copy files to a gs bucket using gsutil rsync in powershell, ignoring some file extensions, but I get the error saying that '.*.scss' is not a command:

```
PS W:\> gsutil -m rsync -x ".*^.gz$^|.*^.scss$^|.*^.less$^|.*^.pdf$^|.*^.zip$" -d -r ./ gs://BUCKET
'.*.scssecho' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program, or a batch file.

# With the originally proposed solution:
PS W:\> gsutil -m rsync -x '.*\.(gz|scss|less|pdf|zip)$' -d -r ./ gs://BUCKET
'scss' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program, or a batch file.
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) has instructions to use `^` as an escape character instead of `\` and escape the `|` character. What am I missing?

Comment: this >>> `NOTE: When using this on the Windows command line, use ^ as an escape character instead of \ and escape the | character.` <<< refers to the CMD.exe shell, not to the powershell.exe shell. ///// have you tried the exclude string with the normal escape chars?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, yes. It also doesn't work in the cmd.

Comment: Yep, powershell is trying to interpret the $'s in the double quotes, so use single quotes instead.

Comment: @js2010 same thing with single quotes.

Comment: Note that gsutil.cmd is a .bat script.  I believe these quoting issues have come up before.

Comment: Can you use Cloud Tools for Powershell instead?  https://cloud.google.com/powershell/

Comment: @js2010 I didn't know about cloud tools for powershell, but it doesn't appears to have rsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use single-quoting (`'...'`), which prevents PowerShell from interpreting the string, notably the `$` chars. in it.
- Since you're passing the regex through to `rsync`, use the usual `\`-escaping for escaping *regex* metacharacters such as `.`
- **Bizarrely, `gsutil` *additionally* requires `cmd.exe` metacharacters to be `^`-escaped**, *irrespective of the calling shell and the original quoting*, which in this case means that **`|` must be escaped as `^|`**

  - [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) mentions the likely reason: the `gsutil` executable is `gsutil.cmd`, i.e. it is implemented as a (`cmd.exe`) *batch file* - though apparently a poorly written one.
  - [AndyO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5040168/andyo) reports that if you create a custom `gsutil.cmd` batch file with the following content, you can avoid the problem (assumes that `python.exe` is in the PATH and is the right version):
    `@python.exe "C:\path\to\gsutil.py" %*`

```bsh
# From PowerShell
gsutil -m rsync -x '.*\.gz$^|.*\.scss$^|.*\.less$^|.*\.pdf$^|.*\.zip$' -d -r ./ gs://BUCKET
```

Additionally, your regex can be simplified:

```bsh
# From PowerShell
gsutil -m rsync -x '.*\.(gz^|scss^|less^|pdf^|zip)$' -d -r ./ gs://BUCKET
```

---

**General points re escaping and quoting:**

It is only in `cmd.exe` that `^` acts as an escape character; in PowerShell, it is `` ` `` (backtick).

Also note that in `cmd.exe` you only need `^` in *unquoted* arguments, not inside `"..."`.

In PowerShell, `'...'` strings are taken literally (verbatim) and require no escaping at all (except for `'` itself as `''`).

Inside `"..."`, expandable strings, `` ` `` must be used to selectively escape `$` characters to be taken as literals, and you can also use escape sequences such as `` `n `` to embed *control characters* (a newline, in this case) and, in PowerShell [Core] 6+, additionally to embed Unicode code characters by their code point (e.g., `` `u{40} `` for the `@` char.)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a .cmd script, you can also run it from cmd or a .bat file, like it was made for.

EDIT:  So it's a .cmd script that calls a python script.  Instead of the .cmd file, if you called this  instead, it might work better:

```
# gsutil.ps1
c:\python27\python.exe c:\gsutil\gsutil $args
```

So with single quotes:

```
.\gsutil.ps1 -m rsync -x '.*^.gz$^|.*^.scss$^|.*^.less$^|.*^.pdf$^|.*^.zip$' -d -r ./ gs://BUCKET
```

EDIT2:

Run the python script directly.  (You can drop the .py if gsutil.cmd is hidden.)

```
$env:path += ';c:\gsutil'
$env:pathext += ';.py'  
gsutil.py -m rsync -x '.*^.gz$^|.*^.scss$^|.*^.less$^|.*^.pdf$^|.*^.zip$' -d -r ./ gs://BUCKET
```

Use of $env:pathext so invoking a .py file doesn't open a new window: https://superuser.com/questions/437790/run-python-scripts-in-powershell-directly